# build android adb for arm processor

Tags: android-ndk

I want to use Android ADB tool on ARM platform.  One of the commands in the build script is:

```
arm-eabi-g++
-I build/libs/host/include/host
-I build/libs/host/include
-I build/libs/host
-I out/host/linux-arm/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libhost_intermediates 
-I dalvik/libnativehelper/include/nativehelper
-I system/core/include
-I hardware/libhardware/include
-I hardware/libhardware_legacy/include
-I hardware/ril/include
-I dalvik/libnativehelper/include
-I frameworks/base/include
-I frameworks/base/opengl/include
-I frameworks/base/native/include
-I external/skia/include
-I tools/include
-I out/host/linux-arm/obj/include
-I prebuilt/ndk/android-ndk-r5b/platforms/android-9/arch-arm/usr/include
-c -fno-exceptions -Wno-multichar -fPIC
-include system/core/include/arch/linux-arm/AndroidConfig.h
-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=0
-DANDROID -fmessage-length=0 -W -Wall -Wno-unused -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -O2 -g -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -UDEBUG
-DANDROID -fmessage-length=0 -W -Wall -Wno-unused -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wsign-promo -DNDEBUG -UDEBUG
-MD -o out/host/linux-arm/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libhost_intermediates/pseudolocalize.o   
build/libs/host/pseudolocalize.cpp
```

I have made sure I have the latest ndk-r5b installed, which is supposed to resolve the STL problem. However, I am still getting the following error:

```
In file included from build/libs/host/pseudolocalize.cpp:1:
build/libs/host/include/host/pseudolocalize.h:4:18: error: string: No such file or directory
In file included from build/libs/host/pseudolocalize.cpp:1:
build/libs/host/include/host/pseudolocalize.h:6: error: 'string' in namespace 'std' does not name a type
build/libs/host/pseudolocalize.cpp: In function 'const char* pseudolocalize_char(char)':
build/libs/host/pseudolocalize.cpp:61: error: 'NULL' was not declared in this scope
build/libs/host/pseudolocalize.cpp: At global scope:
build/libs/host/pseudolocalize.cpp:71: error: 'string' does not name a type
```

Does anyone know how to fix this problem? BTW the building of the intel version of adb works fine by following this link:

http://lackingrhoticity.blogspot.com/2010/02/how-to-build-adb-android-debugger.html

Comment: any time! glad it helped you.

Comment: Year 2018 and still seeing dead links that have not been checked by the content provider :omg. @transistor1 ur link to beaglebone android resources is not anymore.

Comment: @erm3nda removed my comment as the file is no longer hosted. I think Debian apt-based distributions may have an adb  package now. You might want to look into that if you need a binary.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

pseudolocalize.cpp is not needed for adb. And NDK toolchain is intended to build with bionic(Android libc). adb requires glibc(GNU libc) to build.

I created a Makefile to compile adb for Linux/ARM. This Makefile makes statically linked adb executable binary for Linux/ARM, thus it works on Android/ARM as well.

- [standalone Makefile for adb](https://gist.github.com/958335)

How to make.

1. Install [Sourcery G++ Lite for ARM](http://www.codesourcery.com/sgpp/lite/arm) and GNU Make.
2. Download "[Android source code](http://source.android.com/source/downloading.html)".
3. Save [Makefile](https://gist.github.com/958335) as system/core/adb/Makefile.
4. cd system/core/adb; make.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Kazuki. I will definitely try it out tomorrow. How do you know pseudolocalize.cpp is not needed for adb? where can I find the dependency? Also can I just use arm-eabi-g++ under ndk instead of Sourcery G++ lite for ARM? I really appreciate your help. Thanks

Comment: system/core/adb/Android.mk tells the dependency. Of course you can use arm-eabi-g++, but you also need to build GNU libc, or to modify adb to get rid of the dependency for GNU libc.

Comment: Here is what I got after I did everything listed :/root/CodeSourcery/Sourcery_G++_Lite/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/4.5.2/../../../../arm-none-linux-gnueabi/bin/ld: cannot find -lncurses
services.o: In function `dns_service':
/root/myrepo/system/core/adb/services.c:65: warning: Using 'gethostbyname' in statically linked applications requires at runtime the shared libraries from the glibc version used for linking
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [adb] Error 1

Comment: here is what I got when I do: locate libncurses/lib/libncurses.so.5
/lib/libncurses.so.5.7
/lib32/libncurses.so.5
/lib32/libncurses.so.5.7
/root/myrepo/prebuilt/linux-x86/toolchain/i686-linux-glibc2.7-4.4.3/sysroot/usr/lib/libncurses.so
/root/myrepo/prebuilt/linux-x86/toolchain/i686-linux-glibc2.7-4.4.3/sysroot/usr/lib/libncurses.so.5
/root/myrepo/prebuilt/linux-x86/toolchain/i686-linux-glibc2.7-4.4.3/sysroot/usr/lib/libncurses.so.5.6
/usr/lib/libncurses.so
/usr/lib/libncurses.so.5
/usr/lib32/libncurses.so

Comment: Hmm, CodeSourcery Linux toolchain has libncurses. Could you check installation?

Comment: I downloaded the .bin file for graphical installation on Linux. I am using Ubuntu. I was just following the steps of installer and I didn't do anything special. from the result of my locate command, I didn't see libncurses under CodeSourcery. Is this the reason you ask me to check installation? Where is your libncurses located under CodeSoucery folder. Thanks

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood. ncurses is not needed to link. I have updated the Makefile to get rid of the dependency of libncurses. Could you try it?

Comment: Yes, I got rid of the ncurses link. It works now. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I get the following error with Jelly Bean

usb_linux.o: In function `usb_init':
/home/xample/grouper/system/core/adb/usb_linux.c:688: undefined reference to `fatal_errno'
zutil.o: In function `zlibCompileFlags':
/home/fatboy/grouper/system/core/adb/../../../external/zlib/zutil.c:91: undefined reference to `gzflags'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [adb] Error 1

Answer (score 1):

If you need to build the **ADB** (*version 1.0.31*) for ARM take a look  [here](https://github.com/bonnyfone/adb-arm).

The repository contains an **all-in-one build script** and also a **pre-compiled binary for ARM**.

Comment: Based on your script and Arch Linux buildfile I was able to build version 1.0.32. Thank you very much.

Comment: @zgoda Nice! It would be great if you could share your result with us  somehow!

Answer (score 0):

I see the post is quite old, anyway it helped me.
I did not found

> "Sourcery G++ Lite for ARM and GNU Make."

But manage to build/run on/for my ARMv7, following the other steps with gcc 4:4.6.3-1ubuntu5

1. N/A
2. Download "Android source code".
3. Save Makefile as system/core/adb/Makefile. 
   3b. Edit Makefile to CC= gcc and LD= gcc
4. cd system/core/adb; make.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply run the command

```
sudo apt install adb
```

it can handle ARM architecture