# Build ADB for an Android Device

Tags: android, compilation, hardware, adb

I would like to control one android device with another. I have a Samsung Galaxy S III with the USB Host adapter, and would like to control another android phone via ADB. I've looked into this SO post:
[build android adb for arm processor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5904765/build-android-adb-for-arm-processor)
but this isn't necessarily for and Android Host.
Does anyone know how one would go about building ADB for Android? Has it already been done?

Also, would it be "easier" to build ADB against a Linux distro running on the device under emulation? Would control of the device USB port by an emulation app be possible?

Any feedback is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a project with this purpose:
[p2p-adb](https://github.com/kosborn/p2p-adb).
It has an on-the-device adb executable, so one can 'debug'/control other phones with a phone.